# Profile display gets cut off for users with lots of badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was just reading an answer by Jon Skeet and noticed this:

[image: Badges are cut off :(]

Removing `overflow: hidden` fixes it. The whole `<div>` is just a few pixels too far to the right.

Comment: The solution is simple. Jon Skeet must be burninated. >:( [/sarcasm] Yet another change to support the whims of Stack Overlord Jon Skeet :3

Comment: Same for Marc Gravell now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948661/how-to-reduce-number-of-events-generated/27961762#27961762 Basically anyone with 100k+ rep, 100+ gold badges, 1000+ silver badges and 1000+ bronze badges will demonstrates this.

Comment: Just have those users downvote some answers and bounty questions until their rep is within the design limits of the site....

Comment: @rene Jon Skeet can downvote the entire SE network and still have many reputation remaining.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, Jon Skeet can downvote and gain rep.

Comment: This is *Stack Overflow*... stacks and stacks of votes and badges ***will*** overflow.. [status-by-design] ;)

Comment: @zzzzBov Are you telling us that Jon Skeet is actually Chuck Norris?  I _knew_ it!

Comment: @JaneS This may interest you: [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: @Pshemo LOL, that's awesome!  There goes my afternoon's productivity!

Comment: @JaneS Actually Jon Skeet is the only one who can successfully downvote Chuck Norris. ;)

Comment: Note: only reproducible in Firefox 35 on specific zoom levels, notably the default zoom. Could not reproduce on Chrome 40.

Comment: This is so often reported that it should almost be a faq.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Solution: abbreviate silver and bronze badge counts over 1000 by rounding to two significant figures and using the `k` suffix.

At least this delays the issue until Jon or Marc hits 100k bronze badges.

Comment: Well, that scheme can be extended with m. And it will have to be, when Jon finally has his first million reputation. That seems to be the next breaking-point.

Answer (score 22):

I increased the user card width a bit. (not the first time I changed css because of Mr. Jon Skeet).

The change will be on live after our next prod build.

Comment: And he burst it again (or perhaps is *still* bursting it): [User badges not being displayed correctly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287284)

Comment: It's still cut off for me on FireFox windows.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I confirmed this still happens on Windows due to font choice. We're rethinking the solution for this. Instead of increase width for Jon Skeet we'll be reformatting the numbers instead. e.g. using n-k convention.

Comment: @Jin: and there was much rejoicing! :-) Now, to get to > 1k badges..

Comment: And again! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307439/2371861 It's almost like it needs some responsive CSS stuff or something…

Comment: Jin, you must make your css more Jon Skeet proof!

Comment: I still see the issue on my machine. (Firefox, Windows)