# User badges not being displayed correctly

Tags: bug

I've realised the user badges are not being displayed as correctly. [image]

As you can see from the above image the bronze badge count doesn't display fully. The correct badge numbers should be

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't be better to just shorten it up to ● 328 ● 5k ● 6k ?

Comment: @TLama That would definitely be more sensible

Comment: Jon will just blow the layout again once he reaches 1M rep (I presume at this stage it will display as 1000K).

Comment: Strange, I don't see the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28815287/6309

Comment: @VonC In IE 11 it seems to display correctly, however I see it exactly the same as I mentioned in the question in FF and GC

Comment: In Firefox 37.0.1 it’s still cut off in tag wikis under “Top Answerers” (e. g. [c#](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)).