# User badge display is cut off on answers (again)

Tags: bug, design

[This same issue came up in January](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges) and was marked as [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) in February, but I noticed today that it's back again (in some browsers):

[image]

It's not as bad as it was, but maybe the width needs another adjustment.

This was observed in Chrome 41 and IE 8 at default zoom levels. I cannot reproduce in IE 11, and the problem goes away zooming in or out in Chrome.

**EDIT -** What André's suggestion would look like:

[image]

Comment: The best way to fix this would be to use the same formatting as in the reputation number.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: You're suggesting something like `766k • 340 • 5.2k • 6.4k` then?

Answer (score -2):

Yes! This is umm... [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and are currently being worked on by the SE developers.

This has been mentioned in Meta Stack Exchange where as this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185275/a-new-harder-type-of-badge)
asks for more harder, rarer type of badge to be implied. The moderator here (Nick Craver) promptly declines it with the explanation including this:

> As a developer: we have enough trouble with Skeet's badge count overflowing the user card space, adding a badge level isn't going to help.

Yep, they're already on the case. Hopefully, they use your suggestion/ @Andre Daniel's suggestion to solve this problem - including many other users with more than 1k of a certain type of badge.