# Jon Skeet has too many badges!

Tags: bug, design, badges

Again, as our lord achieves 800k rep, and another swath of badges, He again has too many badges to fit the profile box. We must extend it. (again)

Example from [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479)

[image: Example]

[This was fixed 8 months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges), but Jon Skeet has broken Stack Overflow again!

Comment: one can never have too many badges

Comment: What's actual limits from any stated constraints and what's their reasoning?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe he's refering to the little square right up there ^^, after a certain number of badges/rep, they begin to overflow off the square or wrap

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges

Comment: I don't see how he would be past any threshold that was supposedly fixed in that question I linked, can you provide a screenshot? He shouldn't hit another until he either gets to 1000k rep, unless that was fixed to go to 1m too.

Comment: Also, they status completed the other one, and someone mentioned the issue again @KevinB that is the correct question that you linked.

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @bjb568 now that you mention it...yeah, why is that?

Comment: did someone delete my comment due to profanity?

and @bjb568 that's a great question, i really think my question is a question that should be posed again and again as the need arises.

Comment: [This was fixed 8 months ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges), but it looks like Skeet has broken Stack Overflow...again. *Cue Jon Skeet quotes*: "*Jon Skeet does not adapt to Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow adapts to Jon Skeet*".

Comment: "*I increased the user card width a bit. (not the first time I changed css because of Mr. Jon Skeet).*" [*-- Jin*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285543/456814).

Comment: I think your title attracts downvotes...!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier the ittle was intended to be humorous.

Comment: Which it is :) I was trying to state the obvious...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier alright, lol

Comment: The mistagging and lack of an image is what really killed this question, I think. "Profile box" wasn't really specific enough, at first I thought you were talking about badges that show up in [a user's profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), it wasn't until the question was closed as a duplicate that I realized that you're talking about the profile box that shows up in the corner of posts.

Comment: @Cupcake my bad.

Comment: @RobertColumbia:  Let's not introduce an unneeded tag, okay?

Comment: Can we just not edit this question anymore? If I never see another question about Jon Skeet breaking some inconsequential UI, I'll be a much less grumpy user...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Suggested solution...

Rather than extending the box every few months, why not go with the "k" notation, as in:

[image]

Comment: [Jon Skeet is breaking things all across the network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267270/163250). It can't contain his meteoric rise to GREATNESS! The network can no longer handle this level of Skeetness! "*Error: Skeet Overflow*".

Comment: but 5686 looks so much more impressive

Comment: This seems like a logical idea. In his userprofile just don't use k notation.

Comment: @RegisteredUser in my opinion, you shouldn't accept an answer yet, because that would suggest that this bug has been resolved, when in fact it has not.

Comment: I'd prefer to see it at least at the hundreds precision, e.g. 5.7k silver and 6.8k copper.