# Too many badges breaks the "asked" box

Tags: bug, questions, edits

Jon Skeet has broken the CSS [Again!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307439/jon-skeet-has-too-many-badges)

His badges overlap onto the next line when he edits a question, this causes the "asked" box to extend and show some blank space:

[image: Example]

I am seeing this on Windows 10 and IE 11.

---

<sub>Observed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095312/foreach-loop-terminating-before-reaching-end-of-collection#42095312).</sub>

---

I think it is time to [go with the "k" notation.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307446/4631427)

Comment: The badges also overflow for Jon Skeet like that when you click "edited...".

Comment: @Bugs They do, but the bug was mainly that it is causing the "asked" box to extend not that the badges are wrapping. As that was probably the fix to the linked bug report.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate that, it was merely an observation.

Answer (score 11):

My simple fix for this in a quick ascii markup - this is how Jon's user card would look:

```
+--------------------------------+
| | o | Jon Skeet  (LOTS!)       |
| Didn't you hear us? JON SKEET. |
+--------------------------------+
```

That's the only way to make it fixed width and prevent future bugs of this nature.

Comment: I'm only half-joking about this. In 15 more years, we're going to have this issue with every single user on page 1 and 2 of the all-time list. At some point you just get so epic that we just say so :P

Comment: `if (badges.Count > 10000) return "Lots";`

Comment: I realize this is tongue-in-cheek, but as you said, it is a looming problem. What is the objection to using the rounded "k" notation, as is already done for reputation? It's a lot better than wrapping or scroll bars!

Comment: ... just reset their badges. Make them work for it again.