# Jon Skeet has too many badges again!

Tags: bug, design, badges

I was wondering if there was a [`/dev/null` equivalent on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313115/6560716).

On that answer, Jon Skeet's badges overflow.

[image]

[This also happens with @MarcGravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27961762/6560716), and a lot of other high-rep users.

This [was fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284176/6560716), then broke again, [then fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307439/6560716), and now it's broken again.

Can the overflow of their stack of badges be fixed, or **at least wrap the bronze dot with its count**?

We could also go with the `k` notation, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307446/6560716).

Comment: Perhaps its time to move swag-indicators to something you see when you hover over the name.

Comment: Jon Skeet shouldn't have any numbers below his name. Just the name will do.

Comment: Proposal: replace Jon Skeet's Badge Counts with `∞`. More accurate and keeps the current user badge layout.

Comment: Never mind me... I'm here for the memes.

Comment: @Compass in fact, it might be easier to just use `∞` for Jon Skeet's rep, too.

Comment: Also already mentioned on Meta [Badge overflow on users with too many badges](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/276362) (But I don't know if they already "fixed" it after that notification.

Comment: This isn't really a usability problem. It nicely wraps onto the next line. If anything, the "fix" should be making sure that the bronze dot wraps with the count. Sure, we could make the box a little wider, but that'll just break again, like it always does.

Comment: @camden_kid Almost need a [jon-skeet] tag at this point as well

Comment: I nominate we put a filter on the title of Meta questions that throws an error if "Skeet" is mentioned ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan people will just double a letter or put a space aniway ;)

Comment: Is Jon Skeet the nickname of Chuck Norris on SE ?

Comment: Maybe we should start using 7k for his non-gold badges?

Comment: While the choice might be to, yet again, increase the width of the signature block, it seems that it would be fairly simple to add `display:inline-block` to the `.-flair > span:not(.reputation-score)` selector, which would make it fail reasonably: [with the dots staying with the numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zklgq.png). If the choice is to increase the width and the new width does not account for badge counts totaling 13 or 14 digits, it's going to fail again in the not too distant future.

Comment: [Related - Same problem reporting different effect of it though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343191/too-many-badges-breaks-the-asked-box)

Comment: An actual fix would be too add `k` and similar to the badge counts like we already do with rep: `958k 564 7k 8k`

Comment: "or at least wrap the bronze dot with its count" I agree, and [it's trivial to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312042/user-profile-badge-text-wrapping-issue/340696#340696).

Comment: And other solution will be to hide bronze for the one that do not need those anymore. Imagine badge like a currency, when you have enought money you don't mind not knowing how mutch copper coin you have.

Comment: I can't wait for the post about Jon breaking BigInt limitation. But one Jon's problem at a time.

Comment: I think there's only one solution here, reset Jon Skeet's reputation and badges to zero.

Comment: @g00glen00b you realize that "fix" would only be good for a couple of months, right?

Comment: I would like to see them as a bit fancy, little chart, maybe? Then no matter how many of them he would have, it wouldnt break again.

Comment: a simple fix could be to do the `K` like in the rep `958k, G-564, S-7k, B-7k`

Comment: More importantly, Jon Skeet is nearing 1M!

Comment: maybe just removing the `width` attribute on `post-signature` and `user-info user-hover` classes...

Comment: @Pac0 More like [Chuck Norris aspires to be Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Comment: The badge and the number should be separated by a non-breaking space so that they wrap together nicely

Comment: What does Jon Skeet want to do about it?

Comment: [so] should host a guess-when-Jon-Skeet-will-hit-1M raffle with some sweet prizes.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are supposed to solve problems

Comment: Just standardize all numbers as base32 format and be done. That'll hold him till 32767 (VVV)

Comment: I don't see the problem, the site is called stack overflow after all.... <endpun>

Comment: @LunarWatcher it should be <pun>I don't see the problem, the site is called stack overflow after all...</pun>

Answer (score -1):

Maybe just removing the `width` attribute on `post-signature` and `user-info user-hover` classes should solve the issue.

Just my two cents.

Comment: It wouldn't, actually. Consider the case where Jon Skeet posts an answer, and Marc Gravell edits it. Overflow on top of overflow!

Answer (score -29):

Is this really an issue?

Unlike the past times this has happened, the number isn't cut off. Wrapping round seems like a decent enough fix to me.

Comment: [Except it breaks other boxes too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343191/too-many-badges-breaks-the-asked-box)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder a little extra space in a card is hardly my definition of 'broken'

Comment: Well it isn't exactly correct either, so what would you say it is?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder working as intended?

Comment: I wouldn't say so but I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree on that.