# Break in badges list

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, activity-tab

Although I'm relatively far from [Jon Skeet's badge count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343191/too-many-badges-breaks-the-asked-box), the list of badges in the `Profile Page -> Activity Tab -> Accounts List` is broken when viewed with Mobile View **(the bronze number)**.

[image: broken list of badges]

I have Samsung Galaxy S10+, resolution is 412 x 869.
Viewed with Google Chrome.

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if this was [meta-tag:status-declined], because the mobile site is being replaced by the responsive site. By clicking the “full site” link you get the responsive site, but of course, user pages are not yet responsive… Having said all that, I can’t reproduce this on Firefox Nightly 83.0a1, neither on desktop (mobile tester) nor on an actual mobile device.

Comment: I see, well if it will be relevant, I use Chrome Mobile 86.0.4240.110